# How to Target a New Window With Fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(function(){
    $(".fancybox")
     .attr('rel', 'gallery')
     .fancybox({
         type: 'iframe',
         autoSize : false,
              arrows: false,
              topRatio: 0.4,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        padding     : 3,
        margin      : [20, 60, 20, 60], // Increase left/right margin
              helpers : {
                    overlay : {
                            css : {
                                'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)'
                                    }
                             },
                            title: {
                            type: 'outside'
                                  }                          
                            },
         beforeLoad : function() {                    
             this.width = parseInt(this.href.match(/width=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('width=',''));  
             this.height = parseInt(this.href.match(/height=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('height=',''));
         }
     });
    });//]]>  
</script>

<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.example.com/charts/chart1.php?width=440&height=620" rel="gallery" title="Chart1">Chart1</a>
```

I recently installed fancyBox to display various charts, and it's functioning as expected.  However, in certain instances I'd like the fancyBox link to open my site's home page (http://www.example.com/index.php) and illustrate the chart there.

I.e., from the fancyBox link that **isn't** on my home page I'd like to: (1) open a new window, (2) go to my site's home page, and (3) show chart1.php.

Is that practical / possible?  If so: How? Thx. (New to fancyBox)

Comment: I think is possible but you may need to create a script in your homepage to validate the referrer page (where fancybox link was clicked) and if it matches the filter, then launch fancybox accordingly. Is more javascript/jQuery task than fancybox task (and nontrivial amount of lines of code)

Comment: hhhmmm ... that sounds similar to the path I was considering, but was hoping for a built in feature, or something I'd missed, that would lighten the load given the number of charts I have to display.  Thank you.